# responsive website using angular 2 material

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material

I have website made using angular 1 which has menu on top side of website in horizontal form. This menu collapses on small screen devices and appears (pops down) when you  press button. Now I want to switch my web to angular 2 with material but don`t find the exact example because lots of samples are much diferent purpose than I need. What is more that some examples show that you need to use flex in order to get responsive layout. So now I confused whether I should use flex or material 2.

[this one](https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu) is bad for me because it doesn`t extends of wide screen.
can you help me? I am new to angular2 and material.

Comment: use the [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav), and to get a responsive design,you can use `@angular/flex-layout` in combination with material

Comment: @PierreDuc do you want to say that I should use left column for mobile view and right for desktop?

Comment: The Angular Material Documentation might help: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done something close to what you're trying to achieve.

`@angular/flex-layout` gives you the ability to subscribe to screen size changes.

So you might open or close programmatically the sidenav based on screen size.

Here's an [example](https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit/blob/2d40dac6da4be88f3ed9817176310c7d38ed840d/frontend/src/app/features/cockpit/cockpit.component.ts#L100) where I define wether the sidenav should be on side or hover the content :
(because I want over on mobile)

```
this.sidenavMode$ = this.media$
      .asObservable()
      .map((change: MediaChange) => {
        const screenSize = change.mqAlias;
        if (screenSize === 'xs' || screenSize === 'gt-xs' || screenSize === 'sm') {
          return `over`;
        } else {
          return `side`;
        }
      });
```

If you want to open/close it just use the reference of the sidenav and `.close()`.

Comment: thanks but your example takes my time. I look for tag based design like there is col-xs-1 which rearranges very well.